# Force an object to evaluate to false

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm guessing this is probably application specific however I am using node.js - as long as it works in the v8 engine, I don't mind.

I'm trying to create an `Object` that evaluates to false, for example:

```
var Foo = function() { return this; }
var bar = new Foo;
if (bar) // returns false;
```

Is this possible by overriding a certain function of the object, e.g. `toString`?

In case anyone is wondering what use case this may have: it is for returning error objects from functions that normally return a boolean value, but could also possibly have encountered an error and returned my custom error object.

I want any following conditionals to act as if the function returned a false value without having to modify the conditionals to accommodate for the possibility of a non boolean value.

Comment: The final paragraph -- propagating exceptions --  is a good use case for try/catch/throw.  Also, another place you'll see this need, over and over, is with asynchronous callbacks.  In most asynchronous systems on node, callbacks generally are sent two parameters, an error and a data object, and not just one.  If there were a good way to do it with just one object, I suspect people would have adopted that instead.

Comment: To counter the current answers suggesting manipulating `.valueOf()` I'd like to point out that `+({})` is NaN and thus falsy. That should work for any object where valueOf has not been modified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closest you can get is like

```
if (+obj)
```

Where a falsy object defines a `.valueOf()` function that returns `0` or `false`:

```
var o = {
    valueOf: function() {
        return false;
    }
};
if (+o) {
    throw unreachable();
}
```

Comment: This is excellent. Although why is it necessary to convert it to a number? I tried it without the typecast in chrome's console and it still works.

Comment: @George: Otherwise `valueOf` would not be invoked. You must have done something different, because `if (o)` doesn't have the same effect.

Comment: @FelixKling You are right, I was checking whether `o == false`, I just put it in a ternary and it fails unless you convert it to a number.

Comment: @GeorgeReith yes that's a common mistake... `== false` is not the same as  direct `if( .. )`. `==` does type coercion, `if( .. )` does `ToBoolean(..)` right away without coercion.

Comment: Cool that it can be done, but what are the drawbacks? In a future application, writing  `if (!result){ console.log(result.errorString) }` would be a little fragile.  One could write `if (!result && result!==null && typeof result !== undefined) ....` but testing the error property of an object or a separate error variable seems cleaner.

Comment: @Paul yeah obviously this is some WTFey code that should not see light in production, but the original problem was an interesting trivia

Comment: Isn't this actually useless? I don't think having valueOf makes any difference.... `if (+{foo: 'bar'}) throw unreachable()` never throws, and that object doesn't have any valueOf pointing to false

Comment: Meaning any object you cast to a number (+) will resolve as falsy