# Make an object falsy

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to override something on an object in JavaScript so that it appears *‘falsy’*?

For exampe, I create an object like this:

```
function BusyState() { 
  var self = this;
  self.isSet = false;
  self.enter = function () { self.isSet = true; };
  self.exit = function () { self.isSet = false; };
};

var isLoading = new BusyState();
isLoading.enter();
```

I can check for busy like this:

```
if (isLoading.isSet)
```

But I'd like to be able to write this as a shorthand:

```
if (isLoading)
```

Can I do something to my object to have it appear truthy or falsy depending on the value of `isSet`?

Comment: well, "maybe".  But it's a horrible idea...

Comment: Alnitak: How would you "maybe" go around doing it?

Comment: I was looking at Emissary's answer, but I tested it and it doesn't work.

Comment: Rethink your structure! `isLoading` is a terrible object name... Better use someting like `loader.isSet`

Comment: Why would you want to do such a thing? This looks like a serious anti pattern.

Comment: @Yuval, it's no different than how other languages allow the == operator to be overloaded.

Comment: @Paul I tested using `.valueOf` and that doesn't work either.

Comment: @Alnitak: Note in [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18176018/444991) you also have to use `if (+isLoading)` as well, and force the object to be a primitive (and therefore invoke `valueOf()`).

Comment: @Matt sure, so it fails the OP's requirement of just being able to write `if (obj)`.

Comment: @Alnitak: Can't argue with that :).

Comment: Oh, well. Guess it is not a duplicate then.

Answer (score 12):

As far as I know this can't be done. If you read the [ECMAScript-specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.5) you'll see that `if(isLoading)` is evaluated as `if(ToBoolean(isLoading) === true)` and [ToBoolean()](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.2) will always return `true` for an object (as you can see in the table in the specification).